# How to convert this jQuery code to Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert this jquery code

```
$(element).find('.ui.dropdown')
```

to pure JS?

I need to convert a simple code in JQUERY to pure JS.

The `element` is a variable in my code, it comes from this code:

```
$.each($("[action]").toArray(), function(key, element)
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("[action]").forEach(function(element){});`

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: What is the value will `element` hold? Can you console.log(element) and update the question

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti From the bit of code that confused everyone: `element` will be a DOM node because they use `.toArray()`.  It's terrible code, but that's what's been provided.

Comment: what do you want to do with the array? probably `array.map` can be the best choice if you just want to find the elements and convert them to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following?

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[action]')).forEach(function (element, index) {
  element.querySelector('.ui.dropdown')
  // do something to the element
});
```

As noted, [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is only needed if the browser you're running doesn't support [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). For modern browsers you can actually do:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[action]').forEach(function (element, index) {
   element.querySelector('.ui.dropdown')
  // do something to the element
});
```

Comment: `Array.from` is not needed here.

Comment: yep, just for better browser support

Comment: Any browser that doesn't support `.forEach()` on a node list also won't support `Array.from`. For best support use. `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll()).forEach(function(){});`

Comment: @ScottMarcus that's not true... they come from completely separate specifications. The w3c spec for `NodeList.prototype.forEach()` didn't come until a few years after ES2015 `Array.from()`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It is true. No version of IE supports `.forEach` on a node list, nor does it support `Array.from`.

Comment: I think OP wants to convert `$(element).find('.ui.dropdown')` to Vanilla JS

Comment: You're talking about one specific browser. But in any case the edit to your comment makes a lot more sense than the initial one.

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti re-reading your edit, I think you're right and the 1st edit by ScottMarcus removed that!  Just your lack of formatting removed it.

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti That's completely different from what they wrote in their question, from the first revision of the question. I see no evidence of that being their intent.

Comment: @HereticMonkey re-read it, it says *"How to convert this code JQUERY $(element).find('.ui.dropdown') to pure JS?*" then "element comes from this code..."

Comment: @freedomn-m Look at the edit history; that code was not in the first revision, it was added by Sivakumar.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, I just copied and pasted (hence the dodgy CAPS) from revision 1.  And in the edit 1to2 you can see it's been removed

Comment: No @HereticMonkey it was there, for the first edit, it was removed

Comment: @HereticMonkey in case you still haven't seen it, read the _title_ of the _first_ revision.

Comment: @freedomn-m oh, from the *title*. I keep forgetting people hide things there ;).

Comment: @HereticMonkey TBH I'm only just realising it was in the title otherwise I would have mentioned it - in the edit history it shows in bold.  Doesn't show if you click on "source", so, I agree, not in the question.  No idea why it was removed in the first edit even if it's in the title. New users do tend to put the question in the title as it gets around the "you can't ask that" restriction

Comment: @freedomn-m Frankly I usually just downvote these and move on. There are so many sites out there (like the one you linked to) that explain how to convert it's not worth my while. I might see if I can create a canonical or set of them for this...

Comment: @HereticMonkey personally I don't like the whole "you don't *need* to use jquery" - no, we don't *need* to but 20+ lines of code for 1 jquery line... think I'll keep using it thanks.  So I comment that link and also normally move on - but was interested in the silly argument about which feature is "more compatible" with "older" versions of browsers (when neither is...).  Then Sivakumar made the edit that removed all the formatting and I got too involved for my own good :)

Comment: @freedomn-m I didn't remove anything from the OP's question. I just reverted someone's wrong edit to OP's original question. And didn't use `Block Quote` instead used `code sample` to format the line of code. I didn't find what's wrong with my edit?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti See above, I re-reverted as I realised what you were trying to do.  I initially edited because 1) inline instead of block made it harder to read ("removed it" = removed the intent of your edit) 2) spelling mistakes 3) very different from previous edit - so *I did not* look close enough at what you were *trying* to do with the edit because of these and that was my mistake and why I took the time to rectify the mistake (as commented above).

Comment: @Hugo, Thanks for you answers!

Now, i have this code inside the foreach:
$(element).find('.ui.dropdown') 

How can i convert it to pure JS?

Comment: @AndersonDuarte you can do `element.querySelector('.ui.dropdown')`